# Class declaration in python with or without object in parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

What is difference between these two type of class declarations?

```
class ClassName():

class ClassName(object):
```

What does this `object` parameter does?

Comment: In Python 3, there is no difference, since all classes implicitly inherit from `object`

Comment: In Python 3 you don't even need the brackets, just use `class Foo:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 from 2.1, there are two kinds of classes, [new-style and classic](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). Deriving from `object` in Python 2, from 2.1 on, will create a new-style class. In Python 3, there's only one kind, and so both forms are the same.